# React Navigation - navigate to screen to be first in the stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

how can I navigate to a specific screen to be the first on the stack - which means that if I press back from this screen it would close the app (on android back button).

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is the [Reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions.html#reset) `NavigationAction`:

> The Reset action wipes the whole navigation state and replaces it with the result of several actions.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

As in this example above from the docs, you would also only have one `action` which will be a `navigate` to the screen you want to be on top of the stack.